# Radio button not validating in multi step contact form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to validate this form but i am unable to validate these radio buttons, please help. And also want to show alerts if some fields are wrong.

/*** Here is the HTML Code***/

```
<form id="regForm" action="/action_page.php">
      <h1>Register:</h1>
      <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
      <div class="tab">Where do you want to move? *:
        <p><label class="cont">Local
          <input type="radio" name='thing' value='local' data-id="local">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="cont">Domestic
          <input type="radio" name='thing' value='domestic' data-id="domestic">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="cont">International
          <input type="radio" name='thing' value='international' data-id="international">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
    </p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab">Name:
        <div id="local" class="none">
            <p>
                <label class="cont">1 BHK Goods
                  <input type="radio" name='size' value='1 bhk'>
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="cont">2 BHK Goods
                  <input type="radio" name='size' value='2 bhk'>
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="cont">3 BHK Goods
                  <input type="radio" name='size' value='3 bhk'>
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="cont">4 BHK/Villa Goods
                  <input type="radio" name='size' value='3 bhk'>
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="cont">Few Office Goods
                  <input type="radio" name='size' value='Few Office Goods'>
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="cont">Complete Office Goods
                  <input type="radio" name='size' value='Complete Office Goods'>
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="domestic" class="none">
            <p>
                <label class="cont">Complete Home
                  <input type="radio" name='size' value='Complete Home'>
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="cont">Few Household Goods
                  <input type="radio" name='size' value='Few Household Goods'>
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="cont">Complete Home Goods + Vehicle
                  <input type="radio" name='size' value='Complete Home &amp; Vehicle'>
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="cont">Only Vehicle
                  <input type="radio" name='size' value='Only Vehicle'>
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="cont">Few Office Goods
                  <input type="radio" name='size' value='Few Office Goods'>
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="cont">Complete Office Goods
                  <input type="radio" name='size' value='Complete Office Goods'>
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="international" class="none">
            <p>
                <label class="cont">Complete Home
                  <input type="radio" name='size' value='Complete Home'>
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="cont">Few Household Goods
                  <input type="radio" name='size' value='Few Household Goods'>
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="cont">Few Office Goods
                  <input type="radio" name='size' value='Few Office Goods'>
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="cont">Complete Office Goods
                  <input type="radio" name='size' value='Complete Office Goods'>
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab">Select your shifting place and destination:
        <p><input type="text" placeholder="From..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="from"></p>
        <p><input type="text" placeholder="To..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="to"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab">Quailty:
            <p>
                <label class="cont">Economical Quality
                  <input type="radio" name='size' value='Economical Quality'>
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="cont">Premium Quality
                  <input type="radio" name='size' value='Economical Quality'>
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab">Personal Info:
        <p><input type="text" placeholder="Name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="name"></p>
        <p><input type="email" placeholder="From..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="email"></p>
        <p><input type="tel" placeholder="To..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="phone"></p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="terms" value="accepted" checked required=""> I accept AssureShift terms and conditions
    </label>
      </div>
      <div style="overflow:auto;">
        <div style="float:right;">
          <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
          <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
      <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
        <span class="step"></span>
        <span class="step"></span>
        <span class="step"></span>
        <span class="step"></span>
        <span class="step"></span>
      </div>
    </form>
```

/*** Here is the CSS Code***/

```
<style>

#regForm {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 100px auto;
  font-family: Raleway;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 70%;
  min-width: 300px;
}

#regForm h1 {
  text-align: center;  
}

#regForm input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

/* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */
#regForm input.invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

/* Hide all steps by default: */
#regForm .tab {
  display: none;
}

#regForm button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#regForm button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#regForm #prevBtn {
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
}

/* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */
#regForm .step {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  border: none;  
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#regForm .step.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */
#regForm .step.finish {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
    /* The container */
    .cont {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      padding-left: 35px;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 22px;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
    }

    /* Hide the browser's default radio button */
    .cont input {
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    /* Create a custom radio button */
    .cont .checkmark {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 25px;
      width: 25px;
      background-color: #eee;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }

    /* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
    .cont:hover input ~ .checkmark {
      background-color: #ccc;
    }

    /* When the radio button is checked, add a blue background */
    .cont input:checked ~ .checkmark {
      background-color: #2196F3;
    }

    /* Create the indicator (the dot/circle - hidden when not checked) */
    .cont .checkmark:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      display: none;
    }

    /* Show the indicator (dot/circle) when checked */
    .cont input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
      display: block;
    }

    /* Style the indicator (dot/circle) */
    .cont .checkmark:after {
        top: 9px;
        left: 9px;
        width: 8px;
        height: 8px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: white;
    }
    .none {
        display:none;
    }


    </style>
```

/*** Here is the JS Code***/

```
<script>
var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
  //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form...
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    // ... the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      valid = false;
      if (!valid) alert("Must check some thing!");
    }
  }


  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}
</script>
```

I want validate all the possible validations. I have tried the required fields but they are not validating on pressing the next button.

Comment: Please create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that is working, so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
please replace with script with this.




function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");

  x[n].style.display = "block";
  //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
  //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");

  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm(currentTab)) return false;
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form...
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    // ... the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm(currentTab) {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
 switch(currentTab){
        case 0:
        if(x[currentTab].querySelectorAll('input[name="thing"]:checked').length < 1)
        {
             alert("Must check some thing!");
             return false
        }else{
                document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";

        }
        return true;
        break;
        case 1:
        if(x[currentTab].querySelectorAll('input[name="size"]:checked').length < 1)
        {
             alert("Must check some thing!");
             return false
        }
        else{

                document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";

        }
        return true;
        break;
        case 3:
        if(x[currentTab].querySelectorAll('input[name="size"]:checked').length < 1)
        {
             alert("Must check some thing!");
             return false
        }
        else{

                document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
            }
        return true;
        break;
        default:
            for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        // If a field is empty...
        if (y[i].value == "") {
          // add an "invalid" class to the field:
          y[i].className += " invalid";
          // and set the current valid status to false:
          valid = false;
        }
      }


 }

  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:

  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:

  if (valid) {

    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}
```

Comment: it worked properly for radio buttons but when it goes to 3rd tab which are inputs then after filling the details it shows the popup and don't go foreword.

Comment: @UjjawalPoonia let me chek and i ll be back with solution

Comment: sure, i am waiting.

Comment: @UjjawalPoonia i update the script. it will work for you

Comment: Now there is a problem with step indicators, these are not turning green which are filled.

Comment: Can you describe briefly? @UjjawalPoonia

Comment: there is a progress bar in bottom which should turn green if the field is checked/filled but it's only turning the 3rd tab green. Please check that.

Comment: now it is resolved. please check and confirm @UjjawalPoonia

Comment: Yes bro, Thanks a lot for helping me out. i'll send you request on social media for more future help.

Comment: Sure .Most Welcome @UjjawalPoonia

Comment: Can you please help me in validating the pattern of email id?

Comment: Yeah Sure. Where are you stuck in validating pattern of email?

Comment: In the same form i am unable to understand how can i validate if the user has entered the right email address or not.

Comment: @UjjawalPoonia add another code for  email address validation, please put into that your code. and let me know it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function validateEmail(emailField){
        var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;

        if (reg.test(emailField.value) == false) 
        {
            alert('Invalid Email Address');
            return false;
        }

        return true;

}
```

```html
<p><input type="email" placeholder="From..." oninput="this.className = ''" onblur="validateEmail(this);" name="email" ></p>
```

Comment: I have tried it but when i do that, the previous one get's unchecked. Only one can be the right answer here.

Comment: @UjjawalPoonia Ok no problem.